# Helm /bitnami/spark - how to load files to extraVolumeMounts?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, configuration, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spark) to deploy Spark to Kubernetes in GCE. I've configured `extraVolumes` and `extraVolumeMounts` in **values.yaml** and they were created successfully during deployment.

What is the right way to add files to these volumes during the chart's deployment?

```
  ## Array to add extra volumes
  extraVolumes:
    - name: spark-volume

  ## Array to add extra mounts (normally used with extraVolumes)
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: spark-volume
      mountPath: /tmp/new-data
```

Answer (score 9):

Depends where are the files. If you have them inside a repo I would use an [`initContainer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to clone it.

This might look like this:

```
    initContainers:
      - name: git-clone-spark-volumes
        image: alpine/git
        args:
          - clone
          - --single-branch
          - --branch=master
          - --depth=1
          - --
          - https://github.com/your/repo.git
          - /tmp/new-data
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
          - name: spark-volume
            mountPath: /tmp/new-data
    extraVolumes:
      - name: spark-volume
        emptyDir: {}
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: spark-volume
        mountPath: /tmp/new-data
```

This clones the repo (https://github.com/your/repo.git)  into `/tmp/new-data` folder, to where the spark-volume is mounted.

If your files are `key=value` based you could use [`ConfigMap`](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/):

```
$ kubectl create configmap spark-volume --from-file=configure-pod-container/configmap/game.properties --from-file=configure-pod-container/configmap/ui.properties
```

Which can be used:

```
    extraVolumes:
      - name: spark-volume
        configMap:
          name: spark-volume
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: spark-volume
        mountPath: /tmp/new-data
```

This is nicely described on [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Comment: The files are under the charts path. And I'm not able to use a ConfigMap with the helm chart due to the issue https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/1732. So I decided to try load the files to extraVolumeMounts

Comment: Ideally you should have the files added to the image. This seems to be already mentioned at GitHub [Allow helm to add external files to chart deployment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276).

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to add the files to the image?

Comment: Also this issue you have mentioned [https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/1732](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/1732) will be fixed in version 1.1.1 which is described [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/1733/commits/54f6c3b6894ce5ff90964bf933501302b014ebb0).

Comment: @samba, you need to create your own `Dockerfile` based of `bitnami/spark` upload it to a repo which then can be used in Kubernetes Deployment.